# How to interpret the Durbin-Watson test output in R

Tags: r, regression, autoregressive

Just for "train" with linear regression in `R` I'm doing a `Durbin-Watson test` over the residuals of a regression (over stock prices) comparing these with their value at t-1 (lag=1). From my data it's clear that residuals shows a strong autocorrelation. But I understood that from the autoregressive process on the residuals (regressor=1 and R square very close to 1) but I don't understand the `Durbin-Watson output`, that is:

```
        Durbin-Watson test

data:  residui[, 1] ~ residui[, 2]
DW = 1.91, p-value = 0.01888
alternative hypothesis: true autocorrelation is greater than 0
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you specified the test correctly. My impression is that `residui` is a matrix of residuals and their lags. Then the results are non-sensical. The input for the function should be the regression itself (and not its residuals). And the regression must not contain lagged responses because the Durbin-Watson test is not consistent for these and other autocorrelation tests should be used (e.g., Breusch-Godfrey). Maybe you can post a reproducible example that illustrates your analysis approach.

Comment: Yes, 'residui' is a matrix with residuals and their lags. So the input of the function is directly the variable object of the fitting and the explanatory variables..I don't have to first compute the residuals? This is a procedure made automatically by the function? So if I understood well for this test is implied that the lag is 1.

Comment: Yes. The Durbin-Watson test assesses the autocorrelation of residuals of a linear regression fit. The function `dwtest()` expects you to either supply a fitted `lm` object or equivalently the corresponding `formula` plus `data`. The implementation in `dwtest()` only allows to test lag 1. If you want to test more lags I would recommend using `bgtest()` which implements the Breusch-Godfrey test which has several nicer properties. Alternatively, the function `durbinWatsonTest()` in the package `car` also allows to assess more than 1 lag using bootstrap inference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The null hypothesis is that there is no autocorrelation. You can safely reject the null at 2%, there is evidence for autocorrelation.